# UIFont line height

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uifont

Is there any way to set the `lineHeight` of a `UIFont`? I know that `NSAttributedString` can be used to achieve this, but this doesn't suit my case, I would really like to just manipulate `font` of a `UILabel` instead.
I have found that I can manipulate various properties of a font like this:

```
extension UIFont {
    func withAttributes(_ attributes: [UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName : Any]) -> UIFont {
        let newDescriptor = fontDescriptor.addingAttributes(attributes)
        return UIFont(descriptor: newDescriptor, size: pointSize)
    }
}
let newFont = font.withAttributes([.traits: [UIFontDescriptor.TraitKey.weight : UIFont.Weight.bold]])
```

But I haven't found a way to set line height like this.
Either line height or ascender and descender, etc

Comment: Can you explain why `NSAttributedString` "doesn't suit your case"?

Comment: Im suppose to create a function for stylizing various elements of UIView's for entire application. Chaiging font is just one of elements to achieve. I don't want to force anyone to change the way of working with labels, just to achieve this, I wan't to be able to continue working with label.text = "something"

Comment: Working with fonts can be quite fiddly. In this case you can just create your custom `UILabel` subclass and override the setter and getter for `text` to set/get `attributedText` instead.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about this, but I was hoping it could be done with font. Thanks. I'll keep looking, and if I can't find anything, this is probably what Im going to do.